# Augeas support on my Vagrant machine?

Tags: puppet, vagrant, augeas

I'm trying to getting support for augeas on my Vagrant machine.

I tried to install some package with these directives:

```
package { "augeas-tools":   ensure => installed }
package { "libaugeas-dev":  ensure => installed }
package { "libaugeas-ruby": ensure => installed }
```

When i try to use augeas on my manifests, after the vm boot i receive this error:

```
err: Could not find a suitable provider for augeas
```

I'm using the precise32 official box with Vagrant 1.0.3.

Vagrant 1.0.3 has ruby 1.8.7 and puppet 2.7.14

```
$ ruby -v
$ ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
$ puppet help
$ Puppet v2.7.14
```

This is my little manifest with **php** class, included after **apache** class, **mysql** and other classes tested separately.
All things works correctly excepting for the augeas command.

```
class php {

    exec { "apt-update":
        command     => "/usr/bin/apt-get update",
        refreshonly => true;
    }

    package { "augeas-tools":   ensure => installed }
    package { "libaugeas-dev":  ensure => installed }
    package { "libaugeas-ruby": ensure => installed }

    package { "php5":               ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-cli":           ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-xdebug":        ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-curl":          ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-intl":          ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-imap":          ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-mcrypt":        ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-imagick":       ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-sqlite":        ensure => installed }
    package { "php5-gd":            ensure => installed }
    package { "php-apc":            ensure => installed }

    package { 
        "libapache2-mod-php5" : 
            ensure => installed,
            require => Package["php5"]
    }

    augeas { "php-cli":
        require =>  [
                        Package["php5"],
                        Package["augeas-tools"],
                        Package["libaugeas-dev"],
                        Package["libaugeas-ruby"],
                    ],
        context => "/etc/php5/cli/php.ini",
        changes => [
            "set date.timezone Europe/Rome",
            "set short_open_tag Off",
        ];
    }

    augeas { "php-apache":
        require =>  [
                        Package["php5"],
                        Package["augeas-tools"],
                        Package["libaugeas-dev"],
                        Package["libaugeas-ruby"],
                    ],
        context => "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini",
        changes => [
            "set date.timezone Europe/Rome",
            "set short_open_tag Off",
        ];
    }

}
```

After installation of packages, logging in the vagrant machine with "vagrant ssh", i launch:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ ruby -raugeas -e "puts Augeas.open"
#<Augeas:0xb77a3598>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of puppet are you using, and what does your puppet code look like?

Comment: I added the information you've requested. I hope this helps...

Answer (score 8):

I added the following to my Vagrantfile and it augeas started working.

Before declaring puppet provisioner add the following line, if on ubuntu:

**config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install puppet -y"**

This will update your apt packages and then update puppet client whose latest version already has a fix.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that this wasn't fixed in [bug #6907](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6907) that I referenced in my other answer.  That fix only worked for Puppet providers that depended on commands that were then supplied during the run.

For the Augeas provider, it uses an internal Puppet called "features" to check if the ruby-augeas library is available or not.  Features are only being checked once and the results cached, so even after installing the library, this meant the feature still evaluated to false.

I filed this upstream as [bug #14822](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/14822) and have sent a [pull request](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/pull/833) with a fix.  Testing with the patch, I now get this successful run:

```
notice: /Stage[main]//Package[ruby-augeas]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]//Augeas[test]/returns: executed successfully
```

I'm not familiar with Vagrant, but I think you'll need to find a workaround to install the libaugeas-ruby package before the Puppet run in the meantime.

Comment: I'm sure this is the way to find the solution, but not the solution itself. Vote Up! :)

Answer (score 1):

On Puppet 2.7.14, this [should work](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Release_Notes#Allow-providers-to-be-used-in-the-run-they-become-suitable) as the dependencies for providers will only be evaluated when they're needed - i.e. when Puppet needs to run those Augeas resources.

Without the full Puppet log file to confirm, I suspect that it's because you're missing explicit dependencies between the Augeas package(s) and the Augeas resources that need them.  Remember, listing the resources in the manifest in that order doesn't mean Puppet executes it that way.

You could either add requires parameters to every Augeas resource:

```
augeas { "php-cli":
    require => [ Package["php5"], Package["libaugeas-ruby"] ],
    # ...
}
```

Or use the [chaining syntax](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#chaining-resources) to automatically make every Augeas resource depend on a package.  Add this on a line inside the class, but not inside any resource:

```
Package["libaugeas-ruby"] -> Augeas <| |>
```

Comment: I've added all the requires to the augeas directive but the problem still persist. Note: i've edited the main question with the new code including new requires. Thanks for you reply...

Comment: Ok, could you try running this command after libaugeas-ruby is installed?  `ruby -raugeas -e "puts Augeas.open"`

Comment: added to the main question: #<Augeas:0xb77a3598>

Comment: The stuff mentioned in my other answer's been merged, so as of 2.7.20 or 3.0.2 you'll be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After reading answer from @m0dlx I inspect `/home/vagrant/postinstall.sh` file and found that Vagrant uses own copy of Ruby:

> `# The base path to the Ruby used for the Chef and Puppet gems ruby_home="/opt/vagrant_ruby"`

After that I find file `augeas.rb` at `/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/puppet-2.7.19/lib/puppet/provider/augeas/augeas.rb` and edit it, by changing line

```
confine :true => Puppet.features.augeas?
```

to

```
confine :true => :augeas
```

(Shortly speaking I partially apply [patch from @m0dlx](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/commit/d019047c826de02949d2a0b98db38f65716bc5fd).)

After that this error is gone.